# java: anonymous class implements interface; cannot have arguments

Tags: java, maven, freemarker

My following code is giving error !!! in spark.get(new Route("/"). I am new to spark any help will appreciated ?? Any suggestions

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Configuration configuration=new Configuration();
        configuration.setClassForTemplateLoading(sparkclass.class,"/");
        final StringWriter writer=new StringWriter();
        Spark.get(new Route("/"){
            public Object handle(Request request, Response response) throws Exception {
                Template helloTemplate=configuration.getTemplate("hello.ftl");

                HashMap<String,Object>mp=new HashMap<String, Object>();
                mp.put("name","Sumit");
                helloTemplate.process(mp,writer);
                System.out.print(writer);
                return writer;
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Please post the error, otherwise it's hard to guess.

Comment: I recommend http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: java: anonymous class implements interface; cannot have arguments this is the error in line no. 5

Comment: `Spark.get("/", new Route() {...}` should work instead

Comment: "java: anonymous class implements interface; cannot have arguments" , compiler  can't get more obvious than this  . how can an anonymous class  implementing an interface have a constructor that takes in a argument

Comment: thnx Mick Thats solved my problem :)

Answer (score 1):

> An anonymous class cannot have an explicitly declared constructor.
>   Instead, a Java compiler must automatically provide an anonymous
>   constructor for the anonymous class.

Hence you cannot pass arg.

Ref : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.5.1